# Change class of Angular Material elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there any thing similar to angular.js ng-class in angular material?

I want to be able to change the class of elements based on values from the controller and I can't find any way to do so.

In the [samples](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider) I saw a way to change the style attribute but this looks ugly when there are many styles to change.

Comment: what prevents you from using ng-class? angular-material app is still angular...

Comment: Nothing... Tried it and it didn't work. I will update with code snippet. It should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since angular material app is still angular app, ng-class is working the regular way.

```
<div ng-class="{'my-bacground': isClass}">
```

where `'my-bacground'` is name of class and `isClass` is name of variable attached to `$scope`.

Please see [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/K2h6uUFqmEwGrVW1trNB?p=preview) for working example.